# In IIS, will using .net CLR instead of .net Framework work the same for an asp.net MVC site?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8, application-pool, iis-8.5

I've developed a asp.net MVC with Razor site.  It works fine on my PC and on my company's web server.  However, on the client server the site times out and some buttons don't work.  I noticed on the client server, in IIS under the application pool basic settings, there isn't an option for .NET Framework version, instead it says .NET CLR version.  My question is, could that be causing problems on my site?  If so, how do I get the client server's IIS to prompt for Framework version instead of CLR version?  Can you explain why IIS says one thing on one server and another on another server?

Here's what the Client's IIS app pool setting look like where it says CLR instead of Framework:
[image]

Here's the our test server where it says Framework instead of CLR:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct, the difference in verbiage is due to different versions of IIS. Problem should be something else.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know.